# Where do Orcs go when they die?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Men go outside Arda to the Timeless Halls when they die. Elves and Dwarves to the Halls of Mandos, i assume Hobbits have the same fate as Men. so where do Orcs go after they die or are Killed? do they stay within the confines of Arda? rot where they lie? leave the world? is there information pertaining to this?

Comment: Relevant: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102023/how-are-orcs-mortal?lq=1 and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60548/are-tolkiens-orcs-immortal?rq=1

Comment: @randal'thor not really the same question

Comment: @Fingolfin That was a sneaky comment edit! ;-) Agreed it's not the same question, but doesn't the answer there solve this question too?

Comment: @randal'thor that answer doesnt really provide an actual answer as to whether Orcs leave the world or not

Comment: @JasonBaker that may be an answer to this question, where does it say that? which book?

Comment: @Fingolfin OK, rereading I see you're right. I could withdraw my VTC, but it looks as though this question **is** a duplicate of the one Jason linked to.

Comment: Where does what say what? ... *what*?

Comment: @Fingolfin All quotes in user8719's answer in the other question seem to come from HoME 10, *Morgoth's Ring*.

Comment: @randal'thor so the final destination is not specified but are deemed un Elf or Man like